# performFetchWithCompletionHandler only get called ones

Tags: iphone, ios, multitasking, ios7

This is my app Delegate

```
 (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:2];

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *nav=[[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController ] autorelease];
    nav.navigationBar.hidden=YES;
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"########### Received Background Fetch ###########");
    //Download  the Content .

     [self sometask]; // i want to do some task here but this method get called only ones when i try to launch application 

    //Cleanup
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
```

}

so the issue is performFetchWithCompletionHandler is getting called only ones yes i have done that all in info pList that fetch and all but not help please suggest something

Comment: Problem will be in your function "sometask",
Try to run it by commenting line "[self sometask];" 
,I think you simulate Background fetch properly using “Debug -> Simulate Background Fetch” option.
,Make sure that CompletionHandler called

Comment: I have a same problem, is called only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this method should only be called when the system tells you to perform a Background Fetch.

You can simulate that in Xcode here:

[image]